# Cannot Get Batch File To Work To Create Current Date Backups

Tags: batch-file

I created the following batch program to help my friend backup his documents:

```
@echo off
set curr_date=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%
mkdir G:\"Backup %curr_date%"
xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Documents" G:\"Backup %curr_date%" /D/S/H/V/C/F/K/Y
```

The idea is that I put this on his desktop, he runs it once a week or so and it will create a backup of his documents on his external drive (G:).  The folder should be called "Backup (todays date)".

When I run this on his computer it does create a folder on the G: drive that contains his documents and all it's subfolders.  However the folder is named **"My Documents"**, not **"Backup 20150812"**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `/h` switch. `/h` Copies hidden and system files, and, since `Documents` is a system file, it will be copied.

Comment: Works like a charm, and thank you.  But if you can stand to further educate someone whose batch file experience was 30 years ago.... I know that Documents is a system file, and since I wanted it copied to an external I purposely added the /h switch.  I just didn't want it called My Documents.

Comment: I only wanted the Documents file copied to an external drive, and I didn't want the file on the external drive to be called My Documents.  I wanted the external file labeled Backup + current-date.  Removing the /h from my .bat file made it work exactly the way I wanted.  I was only confused by the need for removing that switch.  I thought the /h was necessary since /Documents is a system file.

Comment: Oh, i see now. Answer: You're copying the files inside Documents, not the folder itself, so `/h` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
set "curr_date=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%"
xcopy "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\*.*" "G:\Backup %curr_date%\" /S/H/V/C/F/K/Y
```